# Monodroid Spinner Resource reference error

Tags: xamarin.android, android-spinner

I'm following the spinner from monodroid tutorial. But encountered problem on the resource.[image]

It cannot lookup the SimpleSpinnerItem & SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem on VS 2010. 
Am I missing something?

Edit: Create a partial class to register android runtime as per jonp

```
public partial class Resource
{
    public partial class Layout
    {
        [Register("simple_spinner_dropdown_item")]
        public const int SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem = 17367049;
        [Register("simple_spinner_item")]
        public const int SimpleSpinnerItem = 17367048;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Tried the global resource

[image]

Edit 3: Conflict on my project namespace

I already identified why the const cannot be recognize. It's because of my namespace projectname.Android, it's being duplicated. When I changed it to projectname.AndroidMobile the global resource is there.

See the conflict below.

[image]

Also, to avoid the conflict just use the global:: as per jonp

Comment: You don't need to provide a partial class definition. You need to use the existing Android.Resource type, which already provides those constants.

Comment: Hi Jon, That's the problem. The global const is not recognized, pls see the edit 2 image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to qualify the class, as there are two `Resource` types: [one local to your project](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Android_Resources/Part_1_-_Android_Resource_Basics) (`Your.Namespace.Resource`, located in `Resource.designer.cs`), and [global::Android.Resource](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/). You need to use [global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=F%3aAndroid.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem).

Comment: Hi, jonp i added a partial class and it work. see my edit. Anyway, i just wonder why I need to do these step bec. I already reference the mono.android library. Should the global resource type suppose to be qualify automatically when i created an android project in VS?

Comment: There are two Resource types: the one local to your project and `Android.Resource`. If you don't specify one, the default is the `Resource` in your namespace. Please see the Resource documentation: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Android_Resources

Comment: hi jon, i already did tried the global resource (Android.Resource.Layout.xxxx) and it still fails to recognized. pls see the edit 2 image. Btw, everytime i create a new android project it fails to recognized the global resource but the local is resource is fine.

Comment: Hi jon, thanks for your time and help. I appreciate it. See the edit 3 why im not able to view the const.